# generate lists from 3 dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, list, recursion

I am strugling for some time with an array problem. For example if I have the following 3 dimensional array:

```
import os
import numpy as np

myArray = [[[1,2,3],
            [0,0,0],
            [2,2,2]],
           [[0,1,2],
            [1,1,1],
            [3,3,3]],
           [[2,3,4],
            [5,6,7],
            [8,9,10]]]
```

I would like to define in a recursive way for every position in myArray[0] a list that would store the values on the Z axis so that:

```
list1 = [myArray[0][0][0],myArray[1][0][0], myArray[2][0][0]]  # would be [1,0,2]
list2 = [myArray[0][0][1],myArray[1][0][1], myArray[2][0][1]]  # would be [2,1,3]
list3 = [myArray[0][0][2],myArray[1][0][2], myArray[2][0][2]]  # would be [3,2,4]
list4 = [myArray[0][1][0],myArray[1][1][0], myArray[2][1][0]]  # would be [0,1,5]
list5 = [myArray[0][1][1],myArray[1][1][1], myArray[2][1][1]]  # would be [0,1,6]
list6 = [myArray[0][1][2],myArray[1][1][2], myArray[2][1][2]]  # would be [0,1,7]
list7 = [myArray[0][2][0],myArray[1][2][0], myArray[2][2][0]]  # would be [2,3,8]
list8 = [myArray[0][2][1],myArray[1][2][1], myArray[2][2][1]]  # would be [2,3,9]
list9 = [myArray[0][2][2],myArray[1][2][2], myArray[2][2][2]]  # would be [2,3,10]
```

I guess it has to be something similar to

```
for i in range(len(myArray[0])-1):
    list+str(i) =[something]
```

Do you have any idea how to generate this?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already using numpy:

```
np.swapaxes(np.swapaxes(myArray,0,2),0,1)
```

outputs:

```
array([[[ 1,  0,  2],
        [ 2,  1,  3],
        [ 3,  2,  4]],

       [[ 0,  1,  5],
        [ 0,  1,  6],
        [ 0,  1,  7]],

       [[ 2,  3,  8],
        [ 2,  3,  9],
        [ 2,  3, 10]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the clearest way is to use numpy's array slicing and a list comprehension:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

# use a numpy array
myArray = np.array([[[1,2,3],
                     [0,0,0],
                     [2,2,2]],
                   [[0,1,2],
                    [1,1,1],
                    [3,3,3]],
                   [[2,3,4],
                    [5,6,7],
                    [8,9,10]]])

# get the dimensions of the array
_, x, y = arr.shape

# slice along the appropriate axis
list1,list2,list3,list4,list5,list6,list7,list8,list9 = 
  [myArray[:,i,j] for i,j in product(xrange(x),xrange(y))]
```